# Automatically pretty print in Pycharm console and debugging console

Tags: pycharm, pretty-print

Up until a few weeks ago, when I printed a long dictionary in the pycharm console or the debugging console is was automatically printed "pretty", i.e. it looked like the pprint.pprint output even though I didn't even import pprint.
It also pretty printed when I just typed the name of the dict without an explicit print() command.

I must have changed something because this is not happening anymore. The dicts are now printed in one line, which is completely unreadable.

I went through all the settings, but I can't fix it.

Also, the console width isn't automatically detected correctly anymore. When I print a pandas dataframe, the liine break is after 120 characters and not dynamically at the end of the console window. This also worked before.
I know, that I could fix this with the pandas display options, but I would prefer to fix the underlying problem.

One last thing which might be related: The symbols for printing and soft-wrap, "show variables" and "scroll to end" which appear on the left side of the console do not show up on the debugging console (see the question mark in screenshot).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4FKo.jpg

I tried to fix this with two pycharm versions: 2018.2.5 and 2019.1.3
The operating system is ubuntu 16.04

Thanks for your help

Comment: As I know, pretty printed vars available in `ipython` console